# Can anyone help me analysing the words "luna" and variabilis" in the first sentence of the poem "O fortuna"?

Tags: syntax

This sentence is from the poem "O fortuna" in the work "Carmina Burana". Here is the sentence and my thoughts about it:

> O Fortuna, velut luna statu variabilis, semper crescis aut decrescis; vita detestabilis nunc obdurat et tunc curat ludo mentis aciem, egestatem, potestatem dissolvit ut glaciem.

Thoughts:

I am fairly certain I understand most of this sentence. I understand that "O fortuna" is a vocative and that velut is an adverbial. I am however, confused about "luna" and "variabilis". I understand that " O Fortuna velut luna" means " O destiny, like the moon", but I still don't understand what I should categorise "luna" as. I think it is nominative, so perhaps it is to be considered a subject, but I'm not fully convinced of that. Or perhaps it also is vocative, like "fortuna", but it is not "luna" (the moon) which is being adressed.

And what about "variabilis"? This is an adjective that is technically used about both "Fortuna" and "luna" here, which is also written in nominative (or it could technically be vocative, considering these cases usually have the same forms). But I'm not really sure about that one either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sentence: O Fortuna, velut luna statu variabilis, semper crescis aut
> decrescis; vita detestabilis nunc obdurat et tunc curat ludo mentis
> aciem, egestatem, potestatem dissolvit ut glaciem.

After "O," "Fortuna" must be a vocative.  That much is certain.

As for "luna," we assume that after "velut" it will take the same case as its antecedent.  The most obvious candidate might by "Fortuna"; however, vocatives are tricky, since they are grammatically unconnected to the rest of the sentence.

While "Fortuna" is not grammatically connected to the rest of the sentence, the conjunction *velut* is.  Since the verb is second person singular, we can assume an understood tū as the subject that can provide an antecedent for the complement of *velut*.  Such agreement with understood subjects is a common feature of pro-drop languages and is still the case in a language like Spanish.

Semantically, a vocative signals that a word is being used for direct address and is not grammatically connected to the rest of the sentence.  A nominative and a conjunction like *velut* generally presuppose an underlying proposition to which they are connected.  With this logic, we can treat *luna* and *variabilis* as nominative, yielding a possible translation like:

> O Chance, you, like the moon, variable in state, are always waxing and
> waning.